# what can we say if we just know the global section has a given universal algebra structure?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, universal-algebra

Given an universal algebra A, how to reconstruct a topological space X with some universal (and natural) property (e.g initial,terminal...)in the category of topological spaces whose global sections are A (or some proper category such that the global section of X is exact A)?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by the global sections of a topological space? Do you mean to ask for a topological space $X$ together with a sheaf on $X$? (2) By a "universal algebra $A$", do you mean an algebra of the kind studied in universal algebra, i.e. a set $A$ equipped with functions of various arities? (3) What is the motivation for this question? You're a bit vague about what exactly you want ("some universal and natural property"), and knowing the motivation could help people give better answers.

Comment: for example, in the subcategory of local ringed spaces whose global section of an object are R, we can define spec(R) which is the terminal object in the subcategory. Then, i want to ask 1. weather taking spec(.)  is the unique method to make it be the universal object in almost all natural senses and 2. how to construct something like spec. if we replace R by another universal algebra structure?

Comment: Well, that's not quite true. An affine scheme $\text{Spec}(R)$ can have nontrivial automorphisms, coming from automorphisms of $R$, so it's not terminal. But if $X$ is a locally ringed space with global sections $R$, then there is a unique morphism $f\colon X\to \text{Spec}(R)$ of locally ringed spaces such that the induced map $R\to \Gamma(X) = R$ on global sections is the identity. This is a special case of the fact that $\text{Spec}$ and the global sections functor $\Gamma$ are a pair of adjoint functors between then category of commutative rings and the category of locally ringed spaces.

Comment: This means that $\text{Hom}_{\text{LRS}}(X,\text{Spec}(R)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Ring}}(R,\Gamma(X))$ (both adjoints appear on the right because they're contravariant), so fixing a value of $\Gamma(X)$ (e.g. $R$) and a ring morphism $R\to \Gamma(X)$ (e.g. the identity) specifies a unique map of locally ringed spaces. It seems to me that this adjunction is the kind of universality that you'd want to generalize. Unfortunately, it's something special about *locally* ringed spaces, and I don't know what the analogue of "local ring" is for other varieties of algebras. But I'll think about it.

Comment: thank you. i made a mistake above and i just want to generalize the right hand side of this isomorphism which is replaced by more general homomorphisms, so something i need to do is to give a correct definition of spec. in a correct space.